# Is it possible to get the total number of GC tracked allocated objects programmatically in .NET?

Tags: .net, memory, garbage-collection, runtime, memory-profiling

Is it possible to get the total number of GC tracked allocated objects programmatically in .NET?

You can do this by attaching a memory profiler. However I can't seem to find this figure at runtime. Is it possible? Preferably per generation.

Comment: No, profiler required.  Must be an external program.  Other statistics are available from the .NET performance counters, you see them in Perfmon.exe.

Comment: If you want to put that in as answer, I'll accept it. I've not been able to find any way to do this outside of profiling and seems like the correct answer.